# Only partial AMPscript functionality in EMail template? Or is my code wrong?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript

I am composing an email in ExactTarget/MarketingCloud and I am successfully able to get the recipient's email address (actually I just need the domain) into the email with:

```
%%=Substring(emailaddr,IndexOf(emailaddr,'@'),100)=%%
```

So, I'm sure that `Substring()` and `IndexOf()` DO work in an email [as opposed to microsite and landing pages -- I hear they have different functionality].. but my code that works OUTSIDE of an AMPScript block doesn't work INSIDE? as follows:

```
%%[

/* NOTE: commented out vars?! */

/* var @EMailCount, @lookupDomain */<br>
set @lookupDomain = "homenwork.com"

/* I want this to work to get the recipient's email address to parse inside my AMPscript block */

/* set @emailaddr = RequestParameter("emailaddr") */

/* these don't work in here?! do I need some 'functions' feature enabled or something?! weird

set @nPos = IndexOf(@emailaddr,"@")

set @nPos = Add(@nPos,1)

set @lookupDomain = Substring(@emailaddr,@nPos,100)

*/

set @EMailCount = Lookup("CRTdebug", "CounterField", "EMailDomain", @lookupDomain)

]%% 

EmailCount is %%=v(@EMailCount)=%%
```

Please note that the vars are commented out because something is preventing that syntax because it gave me some error about not having the required comma, but as you can see, there are commas.. I commented them out and the code seems to run fine with me setting values to non-declared variables, which is weird, but whatev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**RequestParameter()**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/microsite_and_landing_page_ampscript_functions/requestparameter/#RequestParameter) is the wrong function to retrieve the email address in an email.  [**AttributeValue()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/attributevalue/) is what you want...and you should be checking to see if it's empty or not before trying your string functions.

Try something like this:

```
%%[

var @EMailCount, @lookupDomain
set @lookupDomain = "homenwork.com"

set @emailaddr = AttributeValue("emailaddr")

if not empty(@emailaddr) then

    set @nPos = IndexOf(@emailaddr,"@")
    set @nPos = Add(@nPos,1)
    set @lookupDomain = Substring(@emailaddr,@nPos,100)

    set @EMailCount = Lookup("CRTdebug", "CounterField", "EMailDomain", @lookupDomain)

else

    set @EMailCount = 0

endif

]%% 

EmailCount is %%=v(@EMailCount)=%%
```

Comment: OK that makes sense - I'll try that.. 

In the meantime, do you know what this is when I try to declare variables?

Unable to generate preview
There is an error in your email. Please contact your customer service representative.
Error 1: Invalid Script VAR Statement
An expected comma is not found in the varible declaration.
Invalid Content: 
    var \@EMailCount, \@lookupDomain

I thought it was because I wasn't declaring them..

Comment: that really didn't format well :-S

Comment: Your variable declarations look fine, except for that errant `<br>`.

Comment: Yes, the checking for it being empty part worked well too.

Comment: p.s. What did you mean by the errant <br>? The line break there? Does  the var line have to be the very first line or something?

Comment: you can just use the Domain() ampscript function instead of substring and index of - https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/domain/

Comment: that is a nifty little function - thx!